# kubeadm init missing optional cgroups

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

It seems that since I've updated to the newest kernel (Ubuntu server 22), I get this message during `kubeadm init`

How to get rid of the following error? :

```
user@kubemaster:~$ sudo kubeadm init
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.24.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: missing optional cgroups: blkio
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is fix for upcoming release https://github.com/kubernetes/system-validators/pull/32

Comment: Even if I use the lates kubadm version (v1.25.4) I got this error and the init process hangs. Is the missing cgroups blkio a problem or not?